# oci_execute dies and return blank oci_error, Why is oci_error null?

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to make a connection to a remote oracle database for the first time from PHP.   However when I try from php I can make a connection but my php dies when using execute query.

Why does oci_error not return anything?

Code:

```
$conn = oci_connect('dbname', 'password', '//xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/orcl');
if(!$conn){
    echo 'DB CON FAILURE';
    exit(0);
} else {
    echo 'DB CON SUCCESS';
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_tables;";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
echo $stid;
oci_execute($stid) or die("Could not execute query: '" . oci_error() . "'");
```

Return:

```
DB CON SUCCESS
Query: SELECT * FROM user_tables;
Resource id #4
Could not execute query: ''
```

My php.ini file shows oci8 is installed and I can connect and execute the above query using sqlplus from the webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the trailing semicolon in your query.

Comment: yes i tried that, same thing. I didnt mean to leave it in there, i was just experimenting.

Comment: actually it suddenly started working when i did that, disregard the other comment, Rob W you are my favorite person

Comment: Cool! Semicolons are to be used for prepared statements, but not for queries. I think the docs discuss the importance of this too. Oracle is pretty specific (unfortunately?).